# Compactness theorem, propositional calculus

Tags: compactness, propositional-calculus

Please help me with this problem.

Prove that if $\land \Phi \models \lor \Psi$ (both $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ infinite) then there exist $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$ from $\Phi$ and $\psi_1,...,\psi_m$ from $\Psi$ such that $\phi_1\land...\land \phi_n\models \psi_1\lor...\lor \psi_m$.
This should follow from the Compactness theorem rather easily but I don't unterstand how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If the logic you're using admits excluded middle, you could convert the hypothesis to $$ ⋀ Φ ∧ ⋀ ¬ ψ ⊢ ⊥. $$
Then Compactness would imply some finite subset $\phi₁ ∧ … ∧ φ_n ∧ ¬ ψ₁ ∧ … ∧ ¬ ψ_m$ of the left hand side entails a contradiction, and from there you can move $\psi₁$ through $\psi_m$ back to the right hand side.

Comment: Oh, nice idea, thanks. Can I use $p_1\land \neg{p_1}$ for $\perp$? ($p_1$ is some variable)

Comment: Sure, if your logic doesn't have a false proposition ⊥ built in.  (I just tend to like using formulations of propositional logic where ⊥ is built in.)

Answer (score 1):

By soundness and completeness of propositional logic we only need to prove

If $\bigwedge \Phi \vdash \bigvee \Psi$ then there exist $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$ from $\Phi$ and $\psi_1,...,\psi_m$ from $\Psi$ such that $\phi_1\land...\land \phi_n\vdash \psi_1\lor...\lor \psi_m$.

Proofs are always finite and therefore involve only finitely many steps. So only finitely many of $\phi_i$s can be used in the proof of $\bigwedge \Phi \vdash \bigvee \Psi$. So we have

There exists $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$ such that $\phi_1\land...\land \phi_n\vdash \bigvee \Psi $

With the same reasoning the last step in the proof of $\phi_1\land...\land \phi_n\vdash \bigvee\Psi $ has to be like this:

$\cdots \Rightarrow (\psi_{i_1}\lor \cdots \lor \psi_{i_m}) \Rightarrow \bigvee\Psi$

Which yields:

There exist $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$ and $\psi_1,...,\psi_m$ such that $\phi_1\land...\land \phi_n\vdash \psi_1\lor...\lor \psi_m$.

Comment: Where have you used Soundness?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 You're right, only completeness is enough here. But my point should be clear.

Comment: It's a good answer, but a lot of it is unnecessary since the OP has asked for a proof using the compactness theorem.  You have essentially included the proof of the compactness theorem inside your answer.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 There are semantic and syntactic versions of compactness theorem. It seemed the OP doesn't know about the syntactic version (since he had no idea about the proof and also semantic entailment was used in the question), so I thought I should explain the syntactic version.